# Why does aluminum chloride have a higher lattice energy than aluminum fluoride?

Tags: energy, ionic-compounds, solid-state-chemistry, covalent-compounds, melting-point

From the table below (source: McMurry's *Chemistry* [1, p. 212]), it is evident that $\ce{AlCl_3}$ has a higher lattice energy than $\ce{AlF3},$ even though $\ce{F}$ is smaller than $\ce{Cl}$. Why is this so?

[image: Table 6.3 Lattice Energies of Some Ionic Solids (kJ/mol)]

However, the melting point of $\ce{AlF3}$ $(\pu{1291 °C})$ is larger than that of $\ce{AlCl3}$ $(\pu{192.4 °C}).$ I think the huge melting point difference is because $\ce{AlCl3}$ is more covalent, while $\ce{AlF3}$ is more ionic. **That being said, does lattice energy account for the covalent and ionic character of compounds?**

#### References

1. McMurry, J.; Fay, R. C.; Robinson, J. K. *Chemistry*, 7th ed.; Pearson: Boston, **2015**. ISBN 978-0-321-94317-0.

Comment: I think this solves the problem: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.quora.com/What-is-trend-of-lattice-energy-in-periodic-table&ved=2ahUKEwjD5cifztjmAhUpDmMBHS3jDicQFjALegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw00vEFxX5wpb7NcPQP2l5J2

Comment: Please don't forget to properly cite the data sources (I added a reference to the textbook I happen to have, you probably have a different edition as the table style is slightly altered). Also, I corrected units typography; feel free to visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: See this site: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/energetics/lattice.html

Answer (score -1):

Lattice energy is a function of the radius ratio, which when tends to 1, improves the packing efficiency of the molecule. Here the radius ratio of the chloride ions and aluminium ions is much closer than the fluoride ions.
You could think of this from the born habers cycle also. Where the electron affinity of chlorine is higher, which leads to overall higher lattice energy. However, the radius ratio logic is much more convincing as the habers cycle logic would require the other parameters like the heat of formation also

Comment: "*… packing efficiency of the molecule*": what *molecule* are you talking about? Also, it's Born–Haber cycle, not "*habers cycle*".